# How to remove underscore from loop items?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove all the _er and _bx from the array, how can I do it? The way I tried doesn't seem to work. I'd like to see a solution where it removes all after `_`, and aswell only the letter that I put in for e.g remove all _ with er after.

```js
const nullValue = {
  collection: [{
      name: "test_er"
    },
    {
      name: "test_bx"
    },
    {
      name: "fred"
    },
    {
      name: "test_er"
    }
  ]
};

const newArr = []
for (let [key, item] of nullValue.collection.entries()) {
  item.name.replace(/_er/g, '')
  newArr.push(item)
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: Maybe ìtem.replace(/_.*/g, "")`

Comment: [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) returns the changed string. The original string is left untouched.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were VERY close with your original code, but the mistake was that `String.replace()` does not operate in-place, but rather *returns* its result. I've modified your code and added a comment below:

```js
const nullValue = {
  collection: [{
      name: "test_er"
    },
    {
      name: "test_bx"
    },
    {
      name: "fred"
    },
    {
      name: "test_er"
    }
  ]
};

const newArr = []
for (let [key, item] of nullValue.collection.entries()) {
  // My change is here
  newArr.push( item.name.replace(/_er/g, '') )
}

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: You don't need a new array. Just change each string in array. .forEach() is fine to use. See below.

Comment: I know you don't need a new array. I took the users original code and made minimal modifications to make it correct.

If I rewrote it for him, he wouldn't have learned anything.

Comment: I disagree. He would have learned a better way to loop for this issue. Also, you can always show the modification AND the new, better way. Those aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: That's not what he asked about though.

Comment: That's irrelevant. He didn't ask for your simple "modification" either. He didn't specify at all how we should answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
const nullValue = {
  collection: [
    {
      name: 'test_er',
    },
    {
      name: 'test_bx',
    },
    {
      name: 'fred',
    },
    {
      name: 'test_er',
    },
  ],
};

nullValue.collection = [
  ...nullValue.collection.map(item => ({
    name: item.name.replace(/_.*$/, ''),
  })),
];

console.log(nullValue);
```

Comment: There is no need to `spread` and `collect` in a new array, as `map` will always return a new array.

Comment: Just use `nullValue.collection = nullValue.collection.map(({ name }) => ( {name: name.replace(/_.*$/, "") }))`

Comment: No need for spread OR .map(). You don't need a new array at all. Use .forEach() or something like that. See below.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.split('_')[0]` with the map method similar to Dmitry's answer... This gives you the *first string* of the ***split array***, *split* at the **underscore**...

```js
const nullValue = {
  collection: [{
      name: "test_er"
    },
    {
      name: "test_bx"
    },
    {
      name: "fred"
    },
    {
      name: "test_er"
    }
  ]
};

nullValue.collection = [ ...nullValue.collection.map( names => ({ name: names.name.split('_')[0], })),]
console.log(nullValue)
```

If you want to keep the original array of objects...

```js
const nullValue = {
  collection: [{
      name: "test_er"
    },
    {
      name: "test_bx"
    },
    {
      name: "fred"
    },
    {
      name: "test_er"
    }
  ]
};
const newArr = { collection : 
[ ...nullValue.collection.map( names => 
  ({ name: names.name.split('_')[0], })),
]}

console.log('newArr = ', newArr)
console.log('nullValue = ', nullValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const nullValue = {
    collection: [
     {
     name: "test_er"
},
    {
     name: "test_bx"
},
    {
     name: "fred"
},
    {
     name: "test_er"
}
    ]
};

nullValue.collection = nullValue.collection.map(i => i.name.replace(/_.*$/, ''))
console.log(nullValue)
```

Answer (score -2):

This is preferable to .map() since you don't need a new array. You just want to change the strings:

```
const nullValue = {
    collection: [
     { name: "test_er" },
     { name: "test_bx" },
     { name: "fred" },
     { name: "test_er" }
   ]
};

nullValue.collection.forEach(i => i.name = i.name.replace(/_.*$/, ''));

console.log(nullValue.collection);
```